# PHP with Composer and PHPstorm, extensions not seen

Tags: php, windows, scoop-installer

I'll try and outline all the details here.

##### Technologies used

- Scoop for different PHP versions
- PhpStorm IDE
- Composer
- Windows system

##### Issue

Currently, when I run the `php --ini` command I get warnings like

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl' (tried: [USER PATH]\scoop\apps\php\current\ext\curl (The specified module could not be found), [USER PATH]\scoop\apps\php\current\ext\php_curl.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0

I have removed the `;` symbol from all the extensions I'm getting this error from. In addition, I have gone to the second file path to verify that the DLL files are also there which they are. I have also updated my `php.ini` file to also set the folder path for the `ext` folder which by that warning it is attempting to look into it to find the extensions.

In addition to the warnings above there is this also.

```text
Configuration File (php.ini) Path:
Loaded Configuration File:         [USER PATH]\scoop\apps\php8.2\current\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: [USER PATH]\scoop\apps\php\current\cli;[USER PATH]\ken.echard\scoop\apps\php\current\cli\conf.d;
Additional .ini files parsed:      [USER PATH]\scoop\apps\php\current\cli\php.ini
```

I have reviewed a number of sources and tried switching the file path. I know that it does see the ini file because when I uncomment another extension another warning shows up. This leads me to the only thing left being something wrong with the extensions or some communication between them. So I started trying to replace the DLL files but that didn't do anything at all.

What I do not understand is that Composer seems to be reactive to the `php.ini` file I'm updating but doesn't see the extension folder.

Can anyone offer up any help to explain what could be wrong or what is going on here?

I noted a bunch in text above but will list again what I have tried.

- Changed PHP versions (it does seem to detect this when running `php --ini`)
- Made sure that the extensions in `php.ini` file are uncommented (this proved that it is reading the .ini file because when I uncommented more more warnings showed up)
- updated the extension path to be the whole file path to the `ext` folder that we want it to look at in addition to uncommenting it.

Comment: It does not look like a composer problem for me. It seems to be an access problem of the server/php not being able to load the extensions.

Comment: @MarkusZeller I agree with you but I did want to note what technologies I was using in case there was a connection I was unaware of. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple php versions exp: 7.4, 8.0 and 8.1
composer can support one version at the time.
you need composer to other php version, again install in php version directory

Comment: David I'm not sure I'm following your statement. Could you elaborate with more details please? If you are saying we can only have one installed at a time does that mean we cannot have them installed at all or does that mean we just need it set within phpstorm to use those PHP files? I know I'm also using phpstorm with this but phpstorm has PHP setups that allow you to setup multiple PHP configs and files to use.